# DropUnwanted Data from Dataframe

Tags: python

I have a large panel dataset of countries. I want to drop a large number of countries and keep a few only for a certain number of year. What would be the appropriate command?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What will be your criteria to drop? I mean which ones you would like to drop? And also please provide a code otherwise no-one can understand how your data-frame looks like. Also please share what you have tried. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can't see your code but you might be able to use boolean masks

```
newdf = df[(df["Countries"] == "Ireland")|(df["Countries"] == "South Africa")]

newdf = newdf[df["Year"] == 2011]
```